# SQL: Display Distinct Record From A Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sample Data:

```
LogID     OrderNo     MaxDate              AnotherDate     Status
NULL      1           2013-07-30 12:01:00  NULL            Pending
NULL      1           2013-07-30 12:01:01  NULL            Pending
NULL      1           2013-07-30 12:01:02  NULL            Pending
NULL      2           2013-07-30 12:02:00  NULL            Pending
NULL      3           2013-08-01 12:30:00  NULL            Pending
```

Expected Output:

```
LogID     OrderNo     MaxDate     AnotherDate     Status
NULL      1           2013-07-30  NULL            Pending
NULL      2           2013-07-30  NULL            Pending
NULL      3           2013-08-30  NULL            Pending
```

**LogID** and **OrderNo** are both foreign keys. Data type for **MaxDate** is **DateTime**

**UPDATE**

Tried using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(OrderNo), LogID, MaxDate, AnotherDate, Status
FROM Logs
```

but is still displaying 3 Order No 1's

Comment: simple `DISTINCT` enough na?

Comment: Even simpler GROUP BY?

Comment: @DavidJashi it sql server not mysql..you to every non grouped column in aggregate function....

Comment: Don't use DISTINCT(orderno), but DISTINCT *.

Comment: @AmitSingh So group all of them.

Comment: @DavidJashi see updated question now if u add Max date in group by than it will show all record simply/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT [LOGID], 
       [ORDERNO], 
       Max([MAXDATE]) MaxDate, 
       [ANOTHERDATE], 
       [STATUS] 
FROM   Logs
GROUP  BY [LOGID], 
          [ORDERNO], 
          [ANOTHERDATE], 
          [STATUS]
```

Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77c73/1) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

I think `select distinct * from <your table>` will work for you

In your case with different times, you could use:

```
 select distinct 
     LogID,
     OrderNo,
     cast(MaxDate as date) as MaxDate,
     AnotherDate,
     Status
 from <your table>
```

Comment: Still displaying multiple order numbers. MaxDate values differ on the timestamp.

Comment: Are the MAXDATE values  actually a different than your sample (i.e. different in the time portion?   SELECT DISTINCT should indeed collaps the records with Order  #1, given the sample data you've presented.   You might want to convert it to a string inside the query to the representation you've shown in your desired output:  SELECT DISTINCT should then work properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Select LogId,
           OrderNo,
          Cast( MaxdATE as Date) as MaxdATE  ,
           AnotherDate,
           Status from
    (
            Select LogId,
            OrderNo,
            MaxdATE,
            AnotherDate,
            Status,
           Row_Number() Over( Partition by OrderNo Order by MaxDate Desc) as Row
            from TableName
    ) T where T.Row=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough for your requirement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       LogID ,
       OrderNo,
       MaxDate ,
       AnotherDate,
       Status
FROM table
```

or if you want to take distinct based on your foreign key you may use this

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LogID ,OrderNo ORDER BY MaxDate ) AS rno,
      LogID ,
           OrderNo,
           MaxDate ,
           AnotherDate,
           Status
    FROM table
 )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rno =1
```

Comment: Your first query won't display distinct since the MaxDate column has various values for the same LogID

Comment: wot about the second? you can extend the partition by for your requirement